# How to query all Foreign keys in each table using SQL?

Tags: sql, database, foreign-keys

I have a database with more than 1600+ tables, and I need to know the foreign keys of each table. I only know how to look for foreign keys manually by clicking the table > column. How to query it and show it in one table along with the table name?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product and system catalogs are completely vendor specific. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Whatever version of SQL you are asking about--This is a faq. Before considering posting please always google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings, names & line numbers & then read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 2):

The SQL standard defines catalog tables and catalog views for this purpose in the schema INFORMATION_SCHEMA.

E.g. "The REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS table has one row for each row in the TABLE_CONSTRAINTS table that has a CONSTRAINT_TYPE value of “FOREIGN KEY”." and "CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE view [...] Identify the columns used by referential constraints, unique constraints, check constraints, and assertions defined
in this catalog and owned by a given user or role.".

There are several tables/views to inspect for your particular purpose.

If your SQL engine supports INFORMATION_SCHEMA, look in the INFORMATION_SCHEMA section of your product's documentation.

If your SQL engine does not support INFORMATION_SCHEMA, then its catalog tables (if any) will be proprietary (and may possibly provide only rudimentary info) and you must inspect your product's doco for the detail of its catalog tables.